# Problem accessing specific column using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables `Listings` & `Reviews` that both have a column `id`.

I want to `inner join` them with `Listings.id = Reviews.listing_id` but when I am specifying something in my `pgadmin`, like `listings.id` or `example.example` it seems like it doesn't recognise it.

I get the error:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "listings"

Do I write something wrong?
Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
  id, listing_url, reviewer_id, reviewer 
FROM 
  public."Listings" 
  INNER JOIN public."Reviews" ON Listings.id = listing_id 
WHERE 
  reviewer = 'Vivek' 
order by 
  reviewer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always qualify *all* columns names so both you and the SQL engine know where the columns come from.  It is not clear where the columns come from.  I've made guesses on where the columns come from:

```
SELECT l.id, l.listing_url, r.reviewer_id, r.reviewer
FROM public."Listings" l INNER JOIN
     public."Reviews" r
    ON l.id = r.listing_id
WHERE r.reviewer = 'Vivek'
ORDER BY r.reviewer_id;
```

Note that this introduces table aliases, which are abbreviations for tables.  This makes it easier to qualify the column names (the default alias is the full table name).

Also, I may be wrong on where the columns come from; your question does not have complete information on the table structure.